# Return row from main table if no results are found in joined tables

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, left-join, distinct

I want to write a query which would return all the rows of the main table after a left join on 2 other tables. In this case, I want to return all the job categories and count the number of jobs that have recured for that job category. If there are no jobs that have recurred, then use 0 for that column.

Recurring job table is having a foreign key `job_id` which links to the `job` table.

There are currently three job categories and so for instance if there are only 2 jobs that have recurred, then not all the job categories would be shown in the results.

This is my query:

```
SELECT 
jc.category_name, COUNT( NULLIF(jc.id, 0) ) job_category
FROM `job_category` jc
LEFT OUTER JOIN `job` ON `job`.`job_category_id` = jc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN `recurring_job` rj ON rj.job_id = `job`.`id` AND rj.id IS NOT NULL
WHERE rj.id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY jc.id;
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the column `job_id` of the table `recurring_job` and remove all the conditions `rj.id IS NOT NULL`:

```
SELECT jc.id, jc.category_name, 
       COUNT(rj.job_id) counter
FROM job_category jc
LEFT OUTER JOIN job ON job.job_category_id = jc.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN recurring_job rj ON rj.job_id = job.id
GROUP BY jc.id, jc.category_name;
```

If `id` is the PRIMARY KEY of `job_category` (it looks like it is), you can omit `category_name` from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Depending on your reqirement, if you want to count the number of distinct recurring jobs you should use:

```
COUNT(DISTINCT rj.job_id)
```

Comment: Your solution works perfectly, but adding a where clause to it still results in the same scenario I presented.
For instance, using a where clause like 


`WHERE job.date_added BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-12-31'`


would still produce only two rows!

Comment: @ErnestElikem you should not use a WHERE clause. Set the conditions in the ON clause: `...LEFT OUTER JOIN job ON job.job_category_id = jc.id AND job.date_added BETWEEN '2021-11-01' AND '2021-12-31'...`

Comment: It works! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Credit to @forpas

There is no need for a `WHERE` clause in my case.

```
SELECT jc.category_name, 
            COUNT(rj.job_id) count
            FROM `job_category` jc
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `job` ON `job`.job_category_id = jc.id AND `job`.`date_added` BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-01-25'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN `recurring_job` rj ON rj.job_id = `job`.id

            GROUP BY jc.id, jc.category_name
```

This outputs all the columns and their corresponding count of recurring jobs.

I hope this is useful.

Comment: Isn't this a copy/paste of my code? Why did you unaccept my answer and posted my code as your answer and accepted it?